# How to disable warnings in generated code in Java gradle project

Tags: java, gradle, generated-code, immutables-library

I would like to have a gradle project that generates no compiler warnings on any code that I write. I would also like to use the [Immutables library](https://immutables.github.io) to generate some of my classes. At the moment I have no found a way to disable warnings for generated code.

Currently I have a `gradle.properties` file that includes:

```
org.gradle.warning.mode = all
immutables_version = 2.7.4
```

In my module's `build.gradle` I have the following relevant portions:

```
apply plugin: "java"

dependencies {
    annotationProcessor("org.immutables:value:${immutables_version}")
    compileOnly("org.immutables:value-annotations:${immutables_version}")
}

project.sourceSets.configureEach { sourceSet ->
    def generatedSourcesDir = project.file("${project.buildDir}/generated/${sourceSet.name}/java")
    generatedSourcesDir.mkdirs()
    sourceSet.java { source ->
        if (!source.srcDirs.contains(generatedSourcesDir)) {
            source.srcDir generatedSourcesDir
        }
    }

    project.tasks.named(sourceSet.getCompileTaskName("java").configure {
        options.annotationProcessorGeneratedSourcesDirectory = generatedSourcesDir
        options.compilerArgs << "-Werror"
    }
}
```

When I try to compile I get output that looks like:

```
Running './gradlew :<module>:compileJava'...

> Task :<module>:compileJava FAILED
warning: Regenerated file with the same content: <generated immutables file>
error: warnings found and -Werror specified
1 error
1 warning
...
```

Is there any compiler setting I can use to exclude warnings for my generated code? I know the [Error Prone compiler](https://errorprone.info) lets you exclude files with `options.errorprone.disableWarningsInGeneratedCode = true` but I don't see anything like that in the normal gradle compile options.

Comment: I am not sure if I understood it correct. You want to compile your project and it does not work? Why are you setting the compile argument `-Werror`? Remove it and your compilation will work again. Or you can just fix the warning in your source code.

Comment: @AndiCover Sorry for not being as clear as I should have been: I would like to use the compiler argument `-Werror` on all source code that I write, but not on generated code. Unfortunately I cannot fix the error in source code because that code has been automatically generated for me.